# Read and Split(Parse) data in java

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to split some simple data from a .txt file. I have found some useful structures on the internet but it was not enough to split the data the way I wanted. I get a string like this:

```
{X:0.8940594 Y:0.6853521 Z:1.470214}
```

And I want to transform it to like this;

```
0.8940594
0.6853521
1.470214
```

And then put them in a matrix in order X=[], Y=[], Z=[]; (the data is the coordinate of an object)

Here is my code:

```
BufferedReader in = null; {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
                for (String part : splited) {
                    System.out.println(part);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

What do I need to add to my code to get the data the way I want?

Right now with this code I receive data like this:

```
{X:0.8940594
Y:0.6853521
Z:1.470214}
```

Comment: So the problem is that the "{" and "}" remain?

Comment: I need only numbers and put the numbers in a matrix. I need to get rid of every other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex `-?\d+\.\d+` for example :

```
String input = "{X:0.8940594 Y:0.6853521 Z:1.470214}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(result);
```

In your case you want to match the real number, you can check the [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/yBYgln/2) .

Comment: What if `X` is `-0.42`?

Comment: yes @Andreas check now i forgot the negative number

Comment: `-?` would be enough. No need for a character class.

Comment: yes @Andreas this correct maybe it can `[-+]` so in this case you need to `[]` right?

Comment: Positive numbers don't normally have a plus in front of them.  If so, then it's the the OP's fault for not telling us.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for thinking the possibility of negative numbers. I get negative datas time to time according to object's position. YCF_L, I could not apply _result_ into my code. What does that suppose to mean in my data?

Comment: @AliNihatUzunalioğlu it is an `ArrayList` so you can loop throw it and use its values, check my answer now

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a regex similar to the following to match and capture the three numbers contained in each tuple:

```
{\s*X:(.*?)\s+Y:(.*?)\s+Z:(.*?)\s*}
```

Each quantity contained in parenthesis is a *capture* group, and is available after a match has taken place.

```
int size = 100;  // replace with actual size of your vectors/matrix
double[] A = new double[size];
double[] B = new double[size];
double[] C = new double[size];
String input = "{X:0.8940594 Y:0.6853521 Z:1.470214}";
String regex = "\\{\\s*X:(.*?)\\s+Y:(.*?)\\s+Z:(.*?)\\s*\\}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
int counter = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    A[counter] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    B[counter] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));
    C[counter] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(3));
    ++counter;
}
```

Comment: Since numbers can be negative, or given in scientific notation, why not just let the `parseDouble()` handle the number syntax? If you then also assume the spaces are exactly as shown, the regex becomes much simpler: `{X:([^ ]+) Y:([^ ]+) Z:([^ ]+)}`, aka `"\\{X:([^ ]+) Y:([^ ]+) Z:([^ ]+)\\}"`. Still +1 for good use of regex.

Comment: Did you intend to use `find()` and not `matches()`? Using `find()` will ignore bad characters before `{` and after `}`.

Comment: @Andreas I agree with your catch on negative numbers, but I would probably leave the possibility for extra whitespace.  The reason I included is because the OP seemed to be implying that a given tuple could be spread out across lines.

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve your problem.

```
String input = "{X:0.8940594 Y:0.6853521 Z:1.470214} ";
        String[] parts = input.split("(?<= )");
        List<String> output = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("*" + i);
            //System.out.println(parts[i]);
            String[] part = parts[i].split("(?<=:)");
            String[] temp = part[1].split("}");
            output.add(temp[0]);
        }

        System.out.println("This List contains numbers:" + output);
```

Output->This List contains numbers:[0.8940594 , 0.6853521 , 1.470214]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{X:0.8940594 Y:0.6853521 Z:1.470214}";
        String x = s.substring(s.indexOf("X:")+2, s.indexOf("Y:")-1);
        String y = s.substring(s.indexOf("Y:")+2, s.indexOf("Z:")-1);
        String z = s.substring(s.indexOf("Z:")+2, s.lastIndexOf("}"));
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex splits on whitespace, but does not remove the curly braces.

So instead of splitting on whitespace, you split on a *class* of characters: whitespace and curly braces.
The line with the regex then becomes:

```
String[] splited = read.split("[\\s+\\{\\}]");
```

Here is an [ideone link](http://ideone.com/k6v29j) with the full snippet.

After this, you'll want to split the resulting three lines on the `:`, and parse the righthand side. You can use [Double.parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for this purpose.

Personally, I would try to avoid long regex expressions; they are hard to debug.
It may be best to remove the curly braces first, then split the result on whitespace and colons. This is more lines of code, but it's more robust and easier to debug.

Comment: IDEONE seems to hide the fact that output starts with a blank line, i.e. the `String[]` starts with an empty string.